# Switch projects in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

How can I switch between all my projects in WebStorm 10 on Linux (including the ones currently closed)?
I know `Ctrl-Alt-Open Bracket`  but I'm trying to also see the projects that I've recently closed - something like SublimeText Quick Switch Project.

Note: I hope this is the right place, I just got shamed away off of programmers.stackexchange as off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install and use **Frame Switcher plugin** -- it does exactly that (using it myself).

Default shortcut is <kbd>Alt + F2</kbd>, which you can change in `Settings | Keymap` if necessary.

Action is also available via Main menu -- `Window | Switch frame`.

Answer (score 0):

Open recent... action allow you to open recently closed projects. It is available via Find action dialog (ctrl-shift-a) or you can assign it to a shortcut of your choice in Settings | Keymap.